# Cisco NSO Yang packages succeed to load but it's oper-status remains down

Tags: xml, ietf-netmod-yang, cisco-nso

Does anybody ever played with Cisco NSO (it is basically a YANG/XML model issue, no need to be NSO expert) ?
If yes, thanks for any help about this issue:

I am developping a new Yang model using Cisco NSO tools.
Find here the Yang model:

```
  module snmpTemp1 {
  namespace "http://com/example/snmpTemp1";
  prefix snmpTemp1;

  import ietf-inet-types {
    prefix inet;
  }

  import tailf-ncs {
    prefix ncs;
  }

  import tailf-common {
    prefix tailf;
  }

  list snmpTemp1 {
    key comm-str;

    uses ncs:service-data;
    ncs:servicepoint "snmpTemp1";

    leaf comm-str {
    tailf:info "snmp-server community-string";
      type string;
    }

    // may replace this with other ways of refering to the devices.
    leaf device {
    tailf:info "Pick any one of the IOS device";
      type leafref {
        path "/ncs:devices/ncs:device/ncs:name";
      }
    }

    // replace with your own stuff here
    leaf access {
    tailf:info "Specify RO or RW";
      type enumeration {
        enum ro;
        enum rw;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When I try to load this package, I get an error:

```
admin@ncs# show packages package snmpTemp1
packages package snmpTemp1
 package-version 1.0
 description     "Template-based snmpTemp1 resource facing service"
 ncs-min-version [ 5.3 ]
 directory       ./state/packages-in-use/1/snmpTemp1
 oper-status file-load-error
 oper-status error-info "snmpTemp1-template.xml:2 Unknown servicepoint: snmpTemp1"
admin@ncs#
```

It seems there is an issue between Yang and XML model:
Find here an extract of the XML:

```
<config-template xmlns="http://tail-f.com/ns/config/1.0"
                 servicepoint="snmpTemp1">
  <devices xmlns="http://tail-f.com/ns/ncs">
    <device>
      <!--
          Select the devices from some data structure in the service
          model. In this skeleton the devices are specified in a leaf-list.
          Select all devices in that leaf-list:
      -->
      <name>{/device}</name>
      <config>
        <!--
            Add device-specific parameters here.
            In this skeleton the service has a leaf "dummy"; use that
            to set something on the device e.g.:
            <ip-address-on-device>{/dummy}</ip-address-on-device>
        -->
        <snmp-server xmlns="urn:ios">
          <community>
            <name>{/comm-str}</name>
            <RO when="{starts-with(access, 'ro')}"/>
            <RW when="{starts-with(access, 'rw')}"/>
          </community>
        </snmp-server>
      </config>
    </device>
  </devices>
</config-template>
```

Does anybody ever played with Cisco NSO (it is basically a YANG/XML model issue, no need to be NSO expert) ?
If yes, thanks for any help.

Regards.

Comment: why you adding servicepoint in xml file?

Answer (score 1):

Generally this kind of error happen if you does not run the make of package before reload NSO.

Note that you must compile your package even if is a pure yang+template without any service java/python logic.

In addition this kind of error happens if you modify the service point **after** package creation, because this breaks the consistency of C-DB